# How toolbar and fragment background to use one gradient color android kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, gradient

I have a problem with creating screen with one gradient color. I have activity which contains toolbar and container which hold fragments. 
 **activity.xml:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_blue_gradient"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backArrowBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow_icon" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/create_resume"
                android:textColor="@color/main_white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">



</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem comes when i replace container with fragment which has the same color ->
        **android:background="@drawable/main_blue_gradient**

the result is two different gradient colors:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting background for fragment or making it's background transparent?

Comment: I got some views which will become visible if i make fragment background transparent :/

Comment: Okay then. You can make container for fragments whole screen and atop of it toolbar. This way fragment will have the same height as activity making gradient ok. Then you will have to add some top margin/padding of toolbar's height size. It is dirty, but will work. Maybe someone will have better idea

Answer (score 1):

You should make your toolbar transparent and make it overlap the `contentContainer`. Then in your fragment, you should add a top padding equal to the toolbar height.